# How to correctly display radiobutton in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to know what is the best way to display a group radio buttons in asp.net mvc 5 application.

Attempt 1:

```
    @Html.RadioButton("SearchBy", "Name", true) <text> Name </text>
    @Html.RadioButton("SearchBy", "Location") <text> Location</text>


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(CoverLetterViewModel viewModel, string searchBy)
    {//somecode}
```

Attempt 2:

```
     //prop
       public string SelectedRoleType { get; set; }
     //view
       <label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedRoleType, "JobSeeker", new { @class = "js-radio", id = "" })
            <span>Job Seeker</span>
        </label>

        <label>
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedRoleType, "Referrer", new { @class = "js-radio", id = "" })
            <span>Referrer</span>
        </label>
      //controller action
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(CoverLetterViewModel viewModel)
        {//somecode}
```

Attempt 3:
Now suppose I have 10 radiobutton, is there any efficient way to create radiobutton. I mean suppose I have a list of radiobuttonitem, Something like below

```
public List<SOME RADIBUTTON ITEM> radiobuttonlist {get;set;}
```

**Question:**

Can we somehow display radiobuttonsame way we handle List of **Dropdown Item** . Can we somehow **avoid hardcoding `"Referrer"` AND `"JobSeeker"` text** in view file.

Comment: Not unless you create a `HtmlHelper` extension method, but you can also use a loop - `foreach (var item in Model.Roles) { @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedRole, item.Name) }`

Answer (score 1):

> Can we somehow display radiobuttonsame way we handle List of Dropdown Item .

No, there is no build-in Html Helper to render a list of radio buttons.

However, you can use simple *foreach* loop and render them one by one.

*FYI: if value and key are same, you could just use `List<string>` instead of `Dictionary<string, string>`.*

### Action Method

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new SampleViewModel
    {
        Items = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"Referrer", "1"}, {"JobSeeker", "2"}}
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

### ViewModel

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Items { get; set; }

    public string SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public SampleViewModel()
    {
        Items = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }
}
```

### View

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    <label>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.SelectedItem, item.Value, 
            new { @class = "js-radio", id = "" })
        <span>@item.Key</span>
    </label>
}
```